# Code Coverage in PhpStorm doesn't update on inner folder

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, phpstorm

I have a strange behaviour with code coverage on PhpStorm 8 with PHP 5.5

I have a class fully covered, but it's nested 2 levels in my file system. If I run the tests with coverage, it doesn't show any coverage.

If I move the class one level up in my folders structure (adapting of course the code to load the class from that place), the coverage shows correctly.

Could I be missing any extra configuration?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in brand new empty project (just some simple class + test file).. or is it specific to your project only. For me it works fine 3 folders deep (but all of them have some files to test -- they are not empty folders).

Comment: It's getting weirder because if I move the files one extra folder deeper, it works fine. All the folders had something to test.

Comment: Also, if I rename the folder that gave me problems, it works fine. The folder name was "strategies", but I didn't think that has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: No real ideas then. I may suggest to submit a new ticket to their Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI .. but you need some reproducible code/project setup in order to investigate the issue. That's why I suggest to try and replicate the folder structure with some basic files (but with same class/file names) and see if issue will remain. You could also look at coverage file generated by PHPUnit and see what's in it -- maybe there are some stuff there that breaks it (wrong path/invalid data?)..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll do that! If I get any feedback I'll post it here